# Cordova access shared pc files from android using same LAN/ wifi

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

I am creating an app in which wants to **access pc files from cordova app if both are in same LAN or wifi.**
We can get access by **IP** and socket api in android.

It is possible in native application as **ES explorer** can do that but couldn't find any plugin for this specific need.all plugins are either network information or file transfer.Is there any way to access files from app or cordova plugin ?

Comment: You'd probably need write your own Cordova plugin to do that - I'd be surprised if there's an existing one to do so

Comment: can I use file plugin and in jave interface file i will make changes